# How to format an entire output (list) of a Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to format the entire output of my Beautiful Soup web scraper here. The output is the following:

```
AT-FVFX1BN7J1WK:Python 522672$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 "/Users/522672/Desktop/Python/Scraper/Beautiful Soup/Python2.py"

[<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="@-yet">@-yet</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="ADDI-DATA">ADDI-DATA</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="ADE-Werk">ADE-Werk</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="Adelmann Umwelt">Adelmann Umwelt</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="Ademco 1">Ademco 1</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="adesso">adesso</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="ADITO Software">ADITO Software</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="ADMOS Gleitlager">ADMOS Gleitlager</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="ads-tec Industrial IT">ads-tec Industrial IT</div>
</div>, <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left">
<div class="ellipsis" title="ADVES">ADVES</div>
</div>]
```

This is the raw output I get when printing company_name but I do not know how to format company_name to just have the company name. So when I do print company_name I simply get an entire list of the companies in just the name form like "@-yet" or "ADDI-ADTA".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

url = 'https://www.vdma.org/en/mitglieder?p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_resource_id=getPage&p_p_id=vdma2publicusers_WAR_vdma2publicusers&s=&page=5'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
company_name = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 text-left")
company_website = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 text-right")
company_adress = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5")
company_contact = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-9")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show the desired result structure/string? I'm not clear on how exactly you'd like this to be formatted. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the BeautifulSoup docs, any guides or tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this CSS selector to get the companies names

*Updated code:*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.vdma.org/en/mitglieder?p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_resource_id=getPage&p_p_id=vdma2publicusers_WAR_vdma2publicusers&s=&page=5'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
with open ("test.txt", "w") as output:
    companies = soup.select('.col-lg-10')
    for company in companies:
        company_name = company.select('.text-left')[0].text.strip()
        company_contacts = company.select('.col-lg-9 .ellipsis')
        # If you want to check the type of every contact
        # for contact in company_contacts:
        #   if "@" in contact.text.strip():
        #       print("Contact is email")
        #   else:
        #       print("Contact is a number")
        output.write(f"Name: {company_name}\nContacts: {', '.join([contact.text.strip() for contact in company_contacts])}\n\n")


        # Output 
        # Name: 2W Technische Informations
        # Contacts: info@2wgmbh.de, (+49 89) 5 20 35-0

        # Name: 3 S Schnecken + Spindeln + Spiralen
        # Contacts: office@3s-gmbh.at, (+43 7613) 50 04

        # Name: 365FarmNet
        # Contacts: info@365farmnet.com, (+49 30) 2 59 32 95 00, (+49 30) 2 59 32 95 01

        # Name: 3D Interaction Technologies
        # Contacts: info@3dit.de, (+49 351) 21 96-74 95
        # ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have one more question, when I parse the contacts I may get the 'email, phone number' and then 'email2, phone2' if I wanted to parse the text so I could export it into an excel file how can I say like every 2 information piece split how would one go about this?

['info@add-yet.de', '(+49 2175) 16 55-0', 'info@addi-data.com', '(+49 7229) 18 47-0', 'info@ade.de', '(+49 781) 2 09-0', 'info@adelmann.de', '(+49 9353) 79 03-0', Thank You!!

Comment: Sure np, so are you gonna standardize the 4 fields each entry you have? Or you want to only obtain whatever the website have, keep in mind this would be in consistent, or you can combine all phones to one Field and use comma as separator? I'm not on my computer rn, lmk if you still need more help with that

Comment: What do you recommend? You have a lot more expertise in this area :).

Comment: I made some updates to the code to make it easier to work with the data  @ThomasVanMelsem